# Char matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix

I have been trying hard with this C++ exercise to no avail..
How do i create a char matrix holding 4 words, with each letter of a word on a char space?
This is my attempt.
I want to use null to know where the string ends. And due to the instructions of the excercise i have to use a char matrix.
As you can see i tried different aproaches with vector[0] and the rest. Neither of them works.

```
int ax = 3;
char ** vector = new char* [ax+1];
for (int i = 0; i < ax; i++){
    vector[i] = new char[10];
}
vector[0] = "F","u","t","b","o","l";
vector[1] = "AUTOmata";
vector[2] = "fUT";
vector[3] = "auto";
vector[ax+1] = NULL;
```

Comment: You're close, but not quite there. `vector[0] = <anything>` nukes the carefully allocated `new char[10]`. Instead, use `strcpy(vector[0], "Futbol")` to copy the literal string into the area you've allocated. Also, the last assignment must assign to `vector[largo]`, not `vector[largo + 1]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. What have you tried so far? Nobody here is going to hold your hand and write all your code for you. Also, please tag a bit more careful.

Comment: Unrelated: `char ** vector`, I strongly advise you choose a different name for that variable, then hit up [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to understand why, and maybe while you're there think about how *that* can be used to make this entire task considerably simpler.

Comment: `new char*[largo+1]` allocates largo+1 `int*`, with indices 0..largo. Assigning to index largo+1 is UB. Do not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been trying hard with this C++ exercise to no avail.. How do i create a char matrix holding 4 words, with each letter of a word on a char space?

No problem. You can use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for this task. In fact from [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you can get a C-string (null terminated since you like them) with [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

```
std::vector<std::string> vector {
    "Futbol",
    "AUTOmata",
    "fUT",
    "auto"
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2b56661176d9382)

---

If you want to use C "features" on the other hand:

```
const int largo = 3;
char** vector = new char* [largo+1];
for (int i = 0; i < largo + 1; ++i)
    vector[i] = new char[10];
strcpy(vector[0], "Futbol");
strcpy(vector[0], "AUTOmata");
strcpy(vector[0], "fUT");
strcpy(vector[0], "auto");
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14bbf05c6a81ed85)